# XText: How can I add Javadoc-like descriptions to my XText language?

Tags: javadoc, xtext

I want to have normal multi-line comments with /* ... */ which can be ignored, and add a /**...*/ Javadoc field before the definition of my entities. This field should be saved together with the object as a description. Is there an elegant way to integrate this with XText and EMF?

Comment: can you elaborate what you want to target with this "feature"? e.g. using it in the code-generator etc? maybe `MultiLineCommentDocumentationProvider` already does what you are looking for

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I want to generate documentation for the files written in my language. The method you suggested `MultiLineCommentDocumentationProvider` does the trick for my use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiLineCommentDocumentationProvider`already provides such a facility